# How can I get out of the search box in Word 2010?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2010

When I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>F</kbd>, type a word, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>, about 50% of the time my cursor is put in the document with the word I searched for selected.

This is the desired behavior. But often, and usually the first time, the search box is cleared instead and I'm returned to the point my cursor was at before I searched.

Can I make it so it always works the first way, like the search function in Firefox?

Comment: strange. Clearing search box and returning to previous position is the behavior when the sought word can't be found, are you sure this happens for you also when word can find it?

Comment: See this comment http://superuser.com/questions/983858/how-can-i-get-out-of-the-search-box-in-word-2010/983886#comment1354067_983886 , which I will edit into the question when I understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

If you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> it goes over all instances of searched text. When you found desired instance you may press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to take cursor to that instance (or more precisely — to focus on selection of that instance in document).

If you don't press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and immediately press <kbd>Esc</kbd> it returns cursor to position where it was before the search.

Comment: There are two different behaviors when you press Enter. The one you're describing, it jumps to the first instance and highlights it in blue (selected) -- in this case it focuses there. But sometimes, when you press Enter and there are multiple matches, it shows you the second match and highlights all matches in orange, but without selecting in blue. That's when you hit Escape and are confused. I can reproduce this about 2 searches out of 5, however, if I hit Enter again when I see there is orange but no blue, I do focus and can safely hit Escape. Thanks for helping me figure that out.